# How to not insert xmlns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to add some XML elements into an XML column in SQL Server.

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
DECLARE @temp XML = '<Rate>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @RateAmt, 1) + '</Rate>'

UPDATE [TableName]
SET [XMLValue].modify('declare namespace ns="http://www.mycompany.com/schema";insert sql:variable("@temp") as last into (/ns:Element1/ns:Element2)[1]') 
WHERE id = @Id
```

Here's the output:

```
<Rate xmlns="">12.00</Rate>
```

So, the code is working, however, how do I remove the xmlns="" attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you inserting a namespace if you don't want one in the xml?

```
DECLARE @RateAmt decimal(9,2) = 12.00
DECLARE @temp XML = '<Rate>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @RateAmt, 1) + '</Rate>'

DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
Column1 Xml
)

INSERT INTO @tempTable(Column1)
SELECT @temp
```

OR

```
UPDATE @tempTable
SET Column1 = (SELECT @temp)


SELECT * FROM @tempTable

<Rate>12.00</Rate>

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Good answer, voted this up, but one hint: You should avoid to create XML via string concatenation... (although this is coming from OP's post). And further more: Your `UPDATE/INSERT` would not work for the OP as he tries to insert this `<Rate>`-element into existing XML...

Comment: The concatenation of strings to create XML was from the initial post, not my design.

Answer (score 0):

There is an accepted answer already (especially concerning your namespace issue), great, just some hints:

There are very rare situation where one should create XML via string concatenation... Especially in connection with strings (*special characters!*), numbers (*format!*) and date/time values (*culture and format!*) it is much better to rely on the implicit translations using `SELECT ... FOR XML ...`

```
DECLARE @RateAmt DECIMAL(12,4)=12.0;
```

This is possible, but not good:

```
DECLARE @temp XML = '<Rate>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @RateAmt, 1) +'</Rate>'
```

Better try this

```
DECLARE @temp XML=(SELECT @RateAmt FOR XML PATH('Rate'));
```

Your attempt to insert this into existing XML can be done the way you do it already (create the XML-node externally and insert it *as-is*), it might be easier to insert the plain value:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,XMLValue XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (N'<Element1><Element2><test>FirstTest</test></Element2></Element1>')
,(N'<Element1><Element2><test>Second</test></Element2></Element1>');

--ID=1: Insert the way you do it:

UPDATE @tbl
SET [XMLValue].modify('insert sql:variable("@temp") as last into (/Element1/Element2)[1]') 
WHERE id = 1

--ID=2: Insert the value of @RateAmt directly

SET @RateAmt=100.00;
UPDATE @tbl
SET [XMLValue].modify('insert <Rate>{sql:variable("@RateAmt")}</Rate> as last into (/Element1/Element2)[1]') 
WHERE id = 2
```

This is Result ID=1

```
<Element1>
  <Element2>
    <test>FirstTest</test>
    <Rate>12.0000</Rate>
  </Element2>
</Element1>
```

And ID=2

```
<Element1>
  <Element2>
    <test>Second</test>
    <Rate>100</Rate>
  </Element2>
</Element1>
```